# A four- or five-time(s)-a-year indulgence

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

[Page 693 of Garner's Modern English reads](https://books.google.es/books?id=18NMAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA607&dq=%22It%20was%20a%20four-%20or%20five-times-a-year%20indulgence%22&hl=es&pg=PA607#v=onepage&q=%22It%20was%20a%20four-%20or%20five-times-a-year%20indulgence%22&f=false)

> When two phrasal adjectives have a common element at the end, and this
> ending portion appears only with the second phrase, insert a
> suspensive hyphen after the unattached words to show their
> relationship with the common element.
>
> > “*It was a four- or five-**times**-a-year indulgence, if that.*”
> >
> > Arthur Miller, “The Bare Manuscript,” New Yorker, 16 Dec. 2002, at 82, 85.
>
> When phrasal adjectives denote durations or amounts, plurals should be
> dropped, *14-**hour**-a-day schedule, three-**week** hiatus*—the exception is with fractions, in which the plural is
> retained <*a two-**thirds** vote*>.

Why isn't it *five-**time**-a-year*, just like the singular nouns in *14-hour-a-day schedule, three-week hiatus.*

Comment: Garner should possibly use 'With phrasal adjectives involving units, plurals should be dropped'. Fractions are essentially numerals, dimensionless.

Comment: Consider the difference between a five-year indulgence, and five-*times-a-year* indulgence. The first is duration. The second is expressing a frequency of repetition. Just like with a "[once-in-a-hundred-years storm](https://www.climatechangepost.com/news/2017/9/11/current-once-hundred-years-flood-levels-along-us-c/)" you would not express this phrase in the singular. But a hundred-year flood would be singular, denoting the length of time it lasted.

Comment: Sorry, but I question "14-hour-a-day schedule," which I'd expect as "14-hour-day schedule." So the parallel drops away from five-times-a-year. It's a rate, like five dollars per hour. Not a "five-dollar-an-hour job." A three-week hiatus is Adjective Verb.

Comment: @GArthurBrown maybe it's different in British English? https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-four-or-five-time-s-a-year-indulgence.3840665/post-19625569

Comment: @GJC Honestly, it's not a phrase that would generally be used adjectivally anyway. Which is, I think, why it retains its form. Like "he's a five-times-the-champion-you'll-ever-be man." You wouldn't change that to "time" because you are preserving an entire idiom. "She's a don't-tell-me-to-eat-my-peas girl."

Comment: @GArthurBrown But in your previous post you said it was because it was not duration but _frequency of repetition_. So what about _a five-year(**s**)-and-not-a-day-less indulgence_ ?

Comment: I was pointing out that it didn't fit the explanation given in your example. I speculated as to why, but I don't know that there is a rule for *frequency of repetition* specifically. As an editor I'd advise against either form of a "five-year(s)-and-not-a-day-less indulgence." But if the author insists on it for style, I'd advise *years.* I think it is arguable either way for long idiomatic modifiers like this. It's not arguable, though, that they are awkward.

Comment: @GArthurBrown Wikipedia disagrees with you over the meaning of [100-year flood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100-year_flood).  Meanwhile the *Hundred Years War* or  *Hundred Years' War* is written in the plural

Comment: @Henry Using the proper names given to wars isn't a particularly good example. Those names are not hyphenated. We'd describe the Hundred Years War as a 116-year war. And as for 100-year flood being ambiguous, that's probably more evidence that the rules given by Garner are really *guidelines.*